# Dictionary .get() method

Tags: python

```
self.dictionary.get(tuple_row_column, self.raiseError())
```

1. Is there a way to raise an Error without defining a method that will manually raise the Error?
2. Even when the dictionary contains the key, the method self.raiseError() is called. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Python is strictly evaluated, meaning that *all* of the arguments to a function call are evaluated *before* the function is called. So `self.raiseError()` necessarily runs, regardless of whether it's needed (in contrast with non-strict or "lazy" languages that do not have this limitation).

If you use subscripting instead of `get`:

```
self.dictionary[tuple_row_column]
```

this will raise `KeyError` if there is no mapping.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `.get` first evaluates the default parameter, as it needs to know what to return in case of a missing key. As pointed out in the comments - if your dictionary contains anything boolean of which evaluates to a `False` (like empty strings, 0, False, [], etc.) this approach will raise an error `self.dictionary.get(tuple_row_column) or self.raiseError()`; either way, the bracket lookup is more pythonic if you want to raise an error if there's a missing key.

For your first question you could just do

```
self.dictionary[tuple_row_column] # Raises KeyError if tuple_row_column not present in dictionary keys.
```

If you want it to raise your error, you could say:

```
try:
    self.dictionary[tuple_row_column]
except KeyError:
    self.raiseError()
```

Comment: `self.dictionary.get(tuple_row_column) or self.raiseError()` won't work if value is `False` in boolean context

Comment: I believe using exceptions for control flow tends to be frowned upon.